# MySQL - is a sub query what's needed here?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, percentage

I currently have such a query:

```
SELECT 
  sec_to_time(avg(t1.sessiontime)) as aloc,
  count(*) as calls
FROM
  table1 AS t1
    inner join
  table2 as t2 ON t1.destination = t2.prefix
WHERE
   t1.card_id = '101' 
AND 
   t1.terminatecauseid = 1
group by t1.destination
```

Example result:

[image]

The 'calls' data is bound to 't1.terminatecauseid = 1' (meaning only answered calls)

I'd like to have a percentage of answered calles from the total calls made.
the same query without the condition (t1.terminatecauseid = 1) will give me the total calls made.

I'd like to know what is the best way to add another column called 'Average Success Rate' that will do:
    total-calls*successful-calls/100
Is a subquery what's needed here? or a brand new and different query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  sec_to_time(avg(t1.sessiontime)) as aloc,
  sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) * 100 / count(*) as Average_Success_Rate,
  sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) as calls
FROM
  table1 AS t1
    inner join
  table2 as t2 ON t1.destination = t2.prefix
WHERE
   t1.card_id = '101' 
group by t1.destination
```

Comment: changing to 'sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) as calls' rather than 'count(*) as calls' returns different results, is your way better ?

Comment: I can't see why it should return different results. `count(*)` counts `null` records too, but that should not be the case here. Can you provide some example data in a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: It does. Im trying to understand if my way was a mistake. the results are different

Comment: I would provide info, but sqlfiddle is currently down -/

Comment: If there's any chance to PM you please let me know, thanks for your help